# Access user defined method properties on query - Esper

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, esper

I implemented a query where i mined data from a database but i have to change it so i mine my data from a custom function in my code. I read the documentation and added the annotation import on the configuration. The query throws that error:

```
Failed to resolve event type, named window or table by name 'path.to.my.class.customfunction'
```

I don't know the type that my function have to return but i tried Arraylist and Hashmaps with key an integer and value a custom class and didn't work.

My final query want to look like this :

```
select * from LocationEvent as loc,
                   ***CustomFuntion()*** as product
                        where loc.id=product.id  ;
```

I kept the structure i used for database connection. I don't know if there is another way to solve this. Thanks.

EDIT: I managed to make call the custom function with that query :

```
select  path.to.class.getProducts() as product from pattern[every timer:interval(3 sec)]
```

My function right now return an ArrayList and the query returns this:

```
[Product{ProductID=124,.....,},Product{...}]
```

So now my problem is that i can't access properties of Product on the query like products.ProductID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a custom function in the from-clause you can use the "method:". The docs have this described here: [Accessing Non-Relational Data via Method](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.7.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#joining_method). The Esper runtime then calls your method to get events/rows.

Comment: Thank you very much again . That worked. I can't understand fully  the difference between method: and not using this tho. I mean how the method can now see the properties of the class of the returning array

Comment: The "method:" is for use in the from-clause. All other method calls (without "method:") can be used in expressions such as the select/where/etc.

Comment: Okey, thanks. The documentation is vast . Thanks for the informations